# How to extract the paper contours in this image (opencv)?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to extract the geometries of the papers in the image below, but I'm having some trouble with grabbing the contours. I don't know which threshold algorithm to use (here I used static `threshold = 10`, which is probably not ideal.

And as you can see, I can get the correct number of images, but I can't get the proper bounds using this method.

Simply applying Otsu just doesn't work, it doesn't capture the geometries.
I assume I need to apply some edge detection, but I'm not sure what to do once I apply Canny or some other.

I also tried sobel in both directions (+ve and -ve in x and y), but unsure how to extract these contours from there.

[image]

How do I grab these contours?

**Below is some previews of the images in the process of the final convex hull results.**

```
    **Original Image**                       **Sharpened**
```

[image]   [image]

```
**Dilate,Sharpen,Erode,Sharpen**         **Convex Of Approximated Polygons Hulls (which doesn't fully capture desired regions)**
```

[image] [image: Convex hulls]

**Sorry in advance about the horrible formatting, I have no idea how to make images smaller or title them nicely in SOF**

Comment: Try using the adaptiveThreshold and experiment with the block size and the offset parameters. If you use Jupyter, use ipywidgets to create interactive sliders to find best matches for the parameters.

Comment: @KnightForked yea, but that would require that I use those "sliders" on all the different images I then try. One slider config may work well with some images, but not with others.

Comment: adaptiveThreshold generally should work better than Otsu in most cases, so it seems so too from your images. You can also try DoG before thresholding.